# Not equal Null not working in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query given below

```
       SELECT 
            B.[Date],           
            B.[Detail],
            B.[Number],
            B.[Total],
            CASE WHEN B.[ApId] != null THEN Ap.Name ELSE B.[Name]END Name,
        FROM [Bacs] B
        LEFT JOIN Table ap ON b.ApId= ap.Id
```

In the `Case When` query I am trying to return the `Name` based on the `b.ApId` value.
But even if `b.ApId` is not null I am getting `B.Name` instead of `Ap.Name`.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Comparisons for null use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` (Unless `ANSI_NULLS` are off, but I wouldn't recommend doing that).

Comment: @ZLK That worked well. Can u please add it as an answer. So that I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!= will evaluate for values, while NULL is not a value.

So you have to either use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` to compare nulls.

```
SELECT 
            B.[Date],           
            B.[Detail],
            B.[Number],
            B.[Total],
            CASE WHEN B.[ApId] is not null THEN Ap.Name ELSE B.[Name]END Name,
        FROM [Bacs] B
        LEFT JOIN Table ap ON b.ApId= ap.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `IS NOT NULL`, `IS NULL` to compare with `NULL` value, Or use `ISNULL`, `COALESCE` function

```
SELECT 
        B.[Date],           
        B.[Detail],
        B.[Number],
        B.[Total],
        CASE WHEN B.[ApId] IS NOT NULL THEN Ap.Name ELSE B.[Name] END Name
        -- ISNULL(Ap.Name, B.[Name]) as Name
        -- COALESCE(Ap.Name, B.[Name],'') as Name
    FROM [Bacs] B
    LEFT JOIN Table ap ON b.ApId= ap.Id
```